# I want to store an id to the localStorage each time when a user drag and drops

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, local-storage

I have two panels. On the left panel I have all the cards with unique id given as id attribute to the div. When a user drag and drops over other panel. I am using the unique id to appendChild on the right side panel, the appending part is working fine. Now I want to store that id in the local Storage so that I can map through them and filter them out from the state which I was using to map all the div cards on left panel and show them on the right panel, so that it would work even if the user refreshes.

```
enter code here  const onCardDrop = (e) => {

        const card = e.dataTransfer.getData('card')
        console.log(card)      // card example 37i9dQZF1DX0u8vIGVgue9

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(card))
        // After this line I want to store the card on local Storage to map the card in future
        // And I want to append the each card id to the local storage to map them easily
        toast();
        let arr;
        
    }
```

I have tried saving into local Storage writing a long code but it is returning the string and every thing getting messed up

Comment: I'm not a React expert, but `appendChild(document.getElementById)`?? I'm not sure that's how you use React at all (that's definitely not how you'd use Angular anyway)

Comment: Please show the code where you are trying to store it in local storage. Note that local storage can only store strings. If you are actually storing ids, that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question right. Local Storage can only store key value pairs of strings (see the [Local Storage Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage))

This is how you store and read a string.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
const str = window.localStorage('foo'); // str === 'bar'
```

To store an object or an array you need to serialize it to whatever string first (I prefer JSON)

```
window.localStorage.setItem('objTest', JSON.serialize({ x: 2, y: 3 }));
const obj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage('objTest'));
window.localStorage.setItem('arrTest', JSON.serialize([1,2,3,4,5]));
const obj = JSON.parse(window.localStorage('arrTest'));
```